# Redirecting to different default routes/components when Angular5 bootstraps

Tags: angular, routes, koa, angular5

I have created an Angular5 application that uses a koa.js backend. An issue has arisen which I am having trouble implementing whereby I would like a user to be able to access a different external facing page on the application depending on the link sent to them in an email. To give further clarity to this problem, here is an explanation.

The App has a login page which is loaded by default when the application bootstraps. this login page uses an AuthGuard to see if the user is logged in and if so they are redirected to the homepage.

Here is the routes file:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    { path: 'acceptinvite', component: SignupComponent, canActivate: [ PublicGuard ]},
    { path: 'forgottenpassword', component: ResetPasswordComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },

    // User Section
    { path: 'users', component: UsersDashboardComponent, canActivate: [ SuperUserGuard ], pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'users/register-user', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [ SuperUserGuard ], pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'users/edit-user/:username', component: EditUserComponent, canActivate: [ SuperUserGuard ], pathMatch: 'full' },

    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },   



    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true, enableTracing: true });
```

And the AuthGuard in question

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _alertService: AlertService
    ) {}

    canActivate() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page
        this._alertService.success(titles.error, messages.authentication.loggedOut, true);
        this._router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }

}
```

The application is accessed via the local url degould-login.dev which is a proxy pass setup in my local nginx config to point the port 4000 on localhost.

Now, my application has the facility for users to be added and for users to request a password reset email. Both of these will send an email to the user with a generated link to the application and a token to check the link is valid. An example of these links that get sent to a user would be as follows:

```
http://degould-login.dev/#/acceptinvite?key=e1061fd2-85de-42b9-89a0-ac8667bd1b84
```

and

```
http://degould-login.dev/#/forgottenpassword?key=e1061fd2-85de-42b9-89a0-ac8667bd1b84
```

I have set this components up and as you can see in my routes file they are not behind the AuthGuard to check for login as these are external facing pages. The problem is, when a user clicks on this link,the link takes them to the application where the Angular bootstrap then runs and they are always redirected back to the login page (as this is the default route in the app routes file). I would like the user to be redirected to the ResetPasswordComponent component or SignupComponent component depending on the links given above.

Is there anyway for this functionality to be implemented into the application or do I have to create separate pages outside of the application in order to implement these two requirements? I was thinking there maybe someway to pass variables to the Angular bootstrap from my Node layer but I couldn't seem to get this to work either.

For clarity, here is my Koa.JS main route file which calls the index.html file which starts the Angualr bootstrap.

index.js (Koa route file)

```
import KoaRouter from 'koa-router';
import fs from 'fs';

const indexRoutes = KoaRouter();

const LOAD_HTML = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(appRoot + '/../client/index.html', {}, (err, data) => {
            if(err) return reject(err);
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
};

indexRoutes.get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.body = await LOAD_HTML();
});

export default indexRoutes;
```